# How can replace content in a document file with another document text, image and table in PHP?

Tags: php, php-5.6, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I have to replace the content of a document result.docx with another document server.docx.

I have implemented the PHP code. I used the tinybutstrong plugin to develop functionality.

But there is a problem. Image and Table from server.docx are not getting.

Only text is getting from server.docx and this text I can see on result.docx.

That means text replaced in result.docx but the image and table are missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Here are the code samples.

```
<?php

include_once('tbszip.php');

$zip = new clsTbsZip();

// Open the first document
$zip->Open('server.docx');
$content1 = $zip->FileRead('word/document.xml');
$zip->Close();

// Extract the content of the first document
$p = strpos($content1, '<w:body');
if ($p === false) exit("Tag <w:body> not found in document 1.");
$p = strpos($content1, '>', $p);
$content1 = substr($content1, $p+1);
$p = strpos($content1, '</w:body>');
if ($p === false) exit("Tag </w:body> not found in document 1.");
$content1 = substr($content1, 0, $p);


// Open the document to replace
$zip->Open('sample.docx');
$content = $zip->FileRead('word/document.xml');

$server = strpos($content, '[Server]');
$content = substr_replace($content, $content1, $server, 8);

// Content replaced and store it in to a newfile.
$zip->FileReplace('word/document.xml', $content, TBSZIP_STRING);
$zip->Flush(TBSZIP_FILE, 'result.docx');
```

Comment: In order for images to work, they you probably need to copy them over, too. In the one sample document I have in front of me, they are stored in the `word/media` folder inside of the zip file. There are also (I think) cross-reference or index files that you need to update, too. I would make your perfect "Result.docx" file in Word, extract both to folders and compare the differences using a tool such as [Beyond Compare](https://scootersoftware.com/)

Comment: The answer is the same as for this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029066/merge-2-file-docx-use-tbszip

Comment: Does this answer your question? [merge 2 file docx use tbszip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029066/merge-2-file-docx-use-tbszip)

Comment: @Skrol29 No, I have tables in my document. It also missing.

Comment: Is there any PHP library or plugin available to replace content of a document with another document (replace text, image, tables)?

Comment: I don‘t know such a library.